# Manwha where the female MC summons beasts so her husband can be recognized

Tags: story-identification, manga

The MC (female) lives for her fiancé. She used a spell that basically made it impossible to hold more magic in order to summon more holy beasts so he can be recognized.

She failed multiple times resulting in her whole body getting destroyed, so much so she couldn't show herself in public and had to live in the shadows. She finds out that her fiancé is actually gay and liked her cousin but they couldn't get married because same sex marriage is banned. She goes back in time and gets her engagement annulled.

The name of the holy beast she mainly uses is a bunny named Azel (Aziel or something. I know it's something like it). It is black and it uses water and ice.

- It is full color
- The MC's hair is white (or blonde)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [*The Soulless Duchess*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=158659), aka *The Duchess with an Empty Soul*.

> The naïve Yvona is ready to do anything for her amazing fiancé! Summon magical beasts and let him take the glory? Sure! Wreck her body for a powerful spell and die for him? Yes! Watch him secretly embrace her trusted cousin Tristan with passion and deride her openly? Oka— wait. What? Just then, Yvona dies... and wakes up a year in the past with a burdened heart. Armed with her knowledge, Yvona's ready to fight for herself. And hmm, maybe form an alliance with the coldhearted Duke of Azentine...

The main character supports her fiancé, letting him take the credit for her summoning, and basically destroys her body as you describe. She reincarnates shortly after witnesses him embracing her (male) cousin.

It's been a while since I read this and I don't recall a specific holy beast, and her hair is brown, not white or blonde. But the other details are so exact I'm pretty certain this is it.

Comment: Thank you very much kind sir